# How would I use BitSet and a BufferedImage to quickly set pixels?

Tags: java, bufferedimage, pixel, bitset

**The Problem**
I'm trying to make a more efficient rendering system from scratch and I've come to the conclusion that using for loops are very inefficient for larger windows.

**Question**
So my question is, can I use BitSet to manipulate the pixels much quicker than using a for loop to set each pixel individually?

**Things You May Need**
The rendering system is very small, as it's more a test than anything. The only thing it currently does is draw rectangles to the screen so I can test the FPS I get.

```
public void drawRect(int offX, int offY, int width, int height, int color)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            pixels[x + offX + this.width * (y + offY)] = color;
}
```

The pixel array is just the data from a BufferedImage using `pixels = ((DataBufferInt) engine.getWindow().getImage().getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();`

I'm not sure how I would go about using the BitSet class with the pixels, but I'm hoping it's faster than the drawRect method. The FPS counter tells me that drawing a single rectangle to the screen of 1980x1080 is roughly 100-130 fps with no consistent clearing to it yet.

**Any help is appreciated, please tell me if the way I have in mind is just plain stupid**

Comment: Why do you think using `BitSet` is a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

`BitSet` isn't really going to be useful for this purpose.  `BitSet` is like a fast, compact *`boolean[]`.*  You might make some progress by replacing the inner loop with  `Arrays.fill(pixels, offX + this.width * (y + offY), offX + width + this.width * (y + offY))`.

All that said, if you're aiming for efficiency, you should be using the tools built into Java, which are going to be better than anything you might write.

Comment: I want to make the engine pixel based and from scratch, but thanks for the suggestion anyway :)

Comment: Unless `Arrays.fill` is replaced with intrinsics, it's just a `for` loop. The extra method call and bounds checking is probably making it slower than a plain loop though.